# Can I use UIPinchGestureRecognizers to distinguish between horizontal and vertical pinches?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view which the user can pinch to grow or shrink.  I'd like this to work along two axes - if the pinch is mostly horizontal, it will grow/shrink the object horizontally, but if the pinch is mostly vertical, it will grow/shrink the object vertically.

Can I achieve this with one or two pinch recognizers, and if so, how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might be able to use a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` for this, but you will have to write code to figure out if the pinch is horizontal or vertical.  I haven't tested this:

```
typedef enum {
    PinchAxisNone,
    PinchAxisHorizontal,
    PinchAxisVertical
} PinchAxis;

PinchAxis pinchGestureRecognizerAxis(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *r) {
    UIView *view = r.view;
    CGPoint touch0 = [r locationOfTouch:0 inView:view];
    CGPoint touch1 = [r locationOfTouch:1 inView:view];
    CGFloat tangent = fabsf((touch1.y - touch0.y) / (touch1.x - touch0.x));
    return
        tangent <= 0.2679491924f ? PinchAxisHorizontal // 15 degrees
        : tangent >= 3.7320508076f ? PinchAxisVertical   // 75 degrees
        : PinchAxisNone;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but  1. I presume you meant `fabsf((touch1.y - touch0.y) / (touch1.x - touch0.x))`, with `x` for last component. 2. You should first check for perfectly vertical, `if (touch1.x == touch0.x) return PinchAxisVertical;` to prevent divide by zero; 3. Note that this tests the angle of your two fingers with respect to each other, not the relative movement of your fingers. The basic trigonometry could be applied to something that actually looked at the deltas, but this is more of "angle of the position of your fingers" rather than "angle of the movement of your fingers".

Comment: You are right about the last `y` needing to be an `x`.  I have fixed that.  Thanks for noting it.  However, there's no need to check for division by zero, as it will produce floating-point infinity, which the subsequent conditional expression handles correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But you must surround your piece of code with `if(sender.numberOfTouches == 2){ ... }` because a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` can fire with 1 touch if you begin with 2 then you remove a finger.